# Python - pip pip2 pip3 pip3.5 packages are installed but cannot be imported in any Python session

Tags: apt, python3, python-2.7, pip

As I am using Xubuntu I thought perhaps this was a better forum than Stackexchange for some questions relating to pip and Python

Today I have encountered troubles with pip and Python.
For some reason I can install packages with `pip install` but the packages are not picked up by Python. If I start any session
Python2.7 Python3.4.3 or Python3.5 and do an import of the installed package it returns the import error

> No module named 'xxx'

It could be one or several environmental variables that is wrong in my setup. But I do not know what the correct settings would be for it to work.

`locate Python.h` gives

> /usr/include/python3.4m/Python.h
>   /usr/local/include/python3.4m/Python.h

but there are more directories in /usr/include

> python2.7
>   python3.4
>   python3.4m
>   python3.5
>   python3.5m

What more information do you need to to help me locate my errors?
Preferably I would like to be able to pip install to each Python version separately, as described here [PIP configuration instructions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/installing/index.html)

As I have been fiddling in the system during the morning I can no longer use the instructions mentioned above. I am lost in the file structure.

```
py@test:/etc/python$ python 3.5 -m pip install urllib3
python: can't open file '3.5': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Even more interesting is that when I tried to fix the problems and reinstall pip

```
sudo python3.5 get-pip.py
```

It was updated a couple of generations

> pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.1MB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.1MB 73kB/s    Installing collected packages: pip     Found existing installation: pip 1.5.6
>       Uninstalling pip-1.5.6:
>         Successfully uninstalled pip-1.5.6 Successfully installed pip-7.1.2

For some reason the system has not protested about the aged pip-installation. But it has protested in the Windows environment.

Earlier I have been able to install packages with pip and it have been usable in Python3.4 with `import` but something has happened lately which has corrupted the connections between pip and Python.

### EDIT:

If I do

```
python2.7 -m pip install urllib3
/usr/bin/python2.7: cannot import name IncompleteRead; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

Answering @dragon2fly questions:

In Python 3.5.0+

```
print(sys.path)
```

> ['', '/home/ike', '/usr/bin', '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
>   '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
>   '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
>   '/home/ike/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
>   '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
>   '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

In Python 3.4.3

> ['', '/home/ike', '/usr/bin', '/usr/lib/python3.4',
>   '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
>   '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
>   '/home/ike/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
>   '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
>   '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

When I use the different pip versions I get:

```
pip show cv2
```

> Metadata-Version: 2.0 Name: cv2 Version: 1.0 Summary: My Blog
>   Distribution Utilities Home-page: http://blog.liuts.com Author:
>   xuyouwen Author-email: 871140705@qq.com License: UNKNOWN Location:
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages Requires:

```
pip3 show cv2
```

> --- Metadata-Version: 2.0 Name: cv2 Version: 1.0 Summary: My Blog Distribution Utilities Home-page: http://blog.liuts.com Author:
>   xuyouwen Author-email: 871140705@qq.com License: UNKNOWN Location:
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages Requires:

I have narrowed down one of the installation errors. I have cv2 installed but cannot import it.

```
python3.5 -m pip install cv2
```

> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cv2 in
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages

However if I import it in Python 3.5.0+

> import cv2
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", > line 1, in 
>   import cv2
>   ImportError: No module named 'cv2'

I have four pip

```
pip pip2 pip3 and pip3.5
```

Comment: what are the output of `import sys; print sys.path` and `$pip show xxx` where `xxx` is your installed package through pip?

Comment: @dragon2fly I will edit the question and add the answers to your questions at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry, you must `import sys; print(sys.path)` in a python interactive season or put it into a `some_name.py` file and do `$python path/to/some_name.py`. `pip show cv2` should be run in shell.

Comment: Yes I misunderstood. Edited @dragon2fly

Comment: Since you are trying to install python-opencv, an easy way is to `sudo apt-get install python-opencv`.  Currently this way is good for python2, if you want to use opencv with python3+, you have to compile it from source and use the source of 3.0+ version not 2.4.xx